# Converting Ecto.DateTime to Erlang datetime tuple using to_erl

Tags: datetime, elixir, ecto

I have a Ecto.DateTime I'm trying to extract information from.

This is working fine:

```
{{y, m, d}, _} = Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(date)
"#{m}/#{d}/#{y}"
```

I'm trying to get the hours/minute/second values now:

```
{{y, m, d}, {h,m,s}} = Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(date)
"#{m}/#{d}/#{y}"
```

But I get this error

> no match of right hand side value: {{2017, 5, 5}, {12, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reusing the variable name `m` in the pattern, which means this'll only work if the month and the minute values are the same. You need to use different names, e.g.

```
{{y, m, d}, {h, min, s}} = Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(date)
```

or

```
{{y, mon, d}, {h, m, s}} = Ecto.DateTime.to_erl(date)
```

```
iex(1)> {a, a} = {1, 2}
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {1, 2}

iex(1)> {a, a} = {1, 1}
{1, 1}
```

Comment: D'oh! Good catch!

Comment: @SergioTapia please consider marking the answer that helped as correct.